# Admob: Interstitial ads showing every time

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

i'm finishing a video application and i'm displaying interstitial ads when leaving the video activity. I just want to show it once every X minutes, but it seems to be showing every time i leave that screen.

This is my activity code.

OnCreate:

```
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
  videoId = b.getString("videoId");
  setContentView(R.layout.youtube_player);

  interstitialAd= new InterstitialAd(this);
  interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_full_screen));
  AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
  interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
  etc...
```

OnBackPressed:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    ShowAds();

}

private void ShowAds() {
    if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        interstitialAd.show();
        interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                super.onAdClosed();
                finish();
            }
        });
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}`
```

of course, it is setted like this into AdMob:

[image]

Note: my application is not published, so it is showing the "preview" o "sample". I am using my ad unit ID:

[image]

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options :

1. Interstitial ads show when I am leaving current Activity but only If I completed X minute on current Activity.

   ```
   boolean isAdShow=false;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       int minute=1;  // X minute

       isAdShow=false;
       new CountDownTimer(minute*60000,1000) {
         @Override
         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

         }

         @Override
         public void onFinish() {
             isAdShow=true;
         }
     }.start();
   }

   private void ShowAds() {

      if (interstitialAd.isLoaded() && isAdShow) {
          interstitialAd.show();
          interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
             @Override
             public void onAdClosed() {
                 super.onAdClosed();
                 finish();
             }
          });
       }else{
          super.onBackPressed();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Don't wait for user to press back button and leave current Activity, just call `ShowAds()` from `onFinish()` method of Timer.

I'll recommend to use 1<sup>st</sup> one because it not violate AdMob Ad policy and user experience too.

**EDIT**

You can also use X times counter, like when `X = 3` i.e After 3 times call of `onCreate()` method make eligible to show Ad.

```
public static int adCounter;
public static final int TIME_COUNTER=3;  //Should be always greater than zero

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    adCounter++;
}

private void ShowAds() {

  if (interstitialAd.isLoaded() && adCounter%TIME_COUNTER==0) {
    interstitialAd.show();
    interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
       @Override
       public void onAdClosed() {
           super.onAdClosed();
           finish();
       }
    });
   }else{
    super.onBackPressed();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i'll check it asap!

Comment: i've tried it and it do work. The main issue is that when i start another video the counter resets, so the ads are never showed if the counter time is bigger than the video. Should i put the counter on the parent activity ?

Comment: @emboole I don't know what is the exact model of your App so I can't say anything for your requirement. This prototype is based on `Ads show after X minutes` so  for small video you will never get Ad but that can be managed, like by getting exact video duration or may be some other way. You can use `X times counter' instead of `X minutes`, please check my updated Answer.