# Interestitial Ads blocks app function in offline

Tags: java, android, admob, interstitial

My app has two ads :

1. Banner
2. Interstitial.

When I open my app the interestitial ad comes first(when data is on). When (data is off) the app doesn't functions properly like button onclick, etc. Only when the ad finished shows up my app works , or else it will not work in offline.

I want to run my app in offline and even if the ad not shows up my app should work.
Hope You'll help me and the question will be helpful for others

My Project

MainActivity.Java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private InterstitialAd interstitial;
    private AdView mAdView;
    Button xxxx;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //GOOGLE ADMOB FIREBASE ADS //

    //Interstitial//

    AdRequest adRequest2 = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);
    interstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-8736194125011489/4511020459");
    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest2);
    interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            displayInterstitial();
        }
    });
}

private void displayInterstitial() {
    if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
        interstitial.show();
    }

    //Banner Ad//

    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest1 = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest1);

    //button//

    xxxx = (Button)findViewById(R.id.xxxx);
    xxxx.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent xxxx = new Intent(MainActivity.this, xxxx.class);
            startActivity(xxxx);
        }
    });
```

Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.jobyreuben.yyyyyyyyy">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".SplashScreen" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

     </activity>


    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>


    <activity
        android:name=".xxxx"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    </application>
    </manifest>
```

Comment: Where do you initialize `xxxxx` button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code, you're adding listener to button in   `displayInterstitial` method that is only called when interstitialAd loaded by `onAdLoaded()` callback method so you got ads on screen first then button works when you close interstitialAd.

And at the counter side when Internet is off, interstitialAd not loaded so `onAdLoaded()` -> `displayInterstitial()` not called and no listener added to your button.

1. `AndroidManifest.xml`

Inside  application tag add AdActivity, if want to use Interstitial Ads

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

2. MainActivity

   ```
   private InterstitialAd interstitial;
   private AdView mAdView;
   Button xxxx;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         xxxx = (Button)findViewById(R.id.xxxx);
         xxxx.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent xxxx = new Intent(MainActivity.this, xxxx.class);
                startActivity(xxxx);
              }
         });

         mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
         AdRequest.Builder adRequestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();
         adRequestBuilder.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR);  // for testing only
         mAdView.loadAd(adRequestBuilder.build()); 

         interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
         interstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-8736194125011489/4511020459");
         interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAdLoaded() {}

                @Override
                public void onAdClosed() {
                     loadIntersitialAd();
                }
         });

         loadIntersitialAd();
     }

     private void loadIntersitialAd(){

         AdRequest interstitialRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
         interstitial.loadAd(interstitialRequest);
     }

     public void displayInterstitial() {
        if (interstitial.isLoaded()) interstitial.show();
     }

     public boolean isInterstitialLoaded(){
       return interstitial.isLoaded();
     }

     @Override
     protected void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       mAdView.resume();
     }

     @Override
     protected void onPause() {
       super.onPause();
       mAdView.pause();
     }

     @Override
     protected void onDestroy() {
       super.onDestroy();
       mAdView.destroy();
    }
   }
   ```

Whenever you want to show Ad call `displayInterstitial()`.

**EDIT**

Call `displayInterstitial()` from `onAdLoaded()` if you want to show Interstitial ad just after ad is loaded but this is not ideal way, loading Ad take some time so you'll get some delay between your Activity come in foreground and Interstitial ad display.

```
interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
         @Override
         public void onAdLoaded() {
              displayInterstitial();   
         }

         @Override
         public void onAdClosed() {
              loadIntersitialAd();
         }
  });
```

**EDIT 2**

Don't load `loadIntersitialAd()` from `onAdClosed()` when you're calling `displayInterstitial()` from `onAdLoaded()` callback method because it creates recursive loop.

```
interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
         @Override
         public void onAdLoaded() {
              displayInterstitial();   
         }

         @Override
         public void onAdClosed() {

         }
  });
```

Comment: Thank you ...The banner ad is showing and the interstitial ad is not showing up while opening the app ?Why ?

Comment: you need to call `displayInterstitial()` whenever you want to show Interstitial Ads, calling from `onAdLoaded()` callback method is not ideal way

Comment: what I can't understand?

Comment: @AbishekAryan The ad keeps on displaying when I close the ad it is displaying another ad...I want to display ad once in 5 minutes

Comment: @JobyReuben you need to apply timer if you want to show ad at particular time, I already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44120462/admob-interstitial-ads-showing-every-time/44121417#44121417) for this requirement

Answer (score 0):

Try putting
 `xxxx = (Button)findViewById(R.id.xxxx);` 
before `AdRequest adRequest2 = new AdRequest.Builder().build();`